# ng-repeat and ng-click not playing well

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="myFunc('{{ item.name }}')">
```

I can't seem to get `ng-click` to pass the varible value of `item.name`. It actually sends:

```
{{ item.name }}
```

An example in Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dq5KA3?p=preview

In the console it looks ok, but doesn't actually work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-click` is actually an [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)expression, so you should be able to set it as `ng-click='myFunc(item.name)'`. This will pass the actual value of `item.name` rather than trying to pass the string value of the raw text as your current implementation is doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="myFunc(item.name)">{{item.name}}
</li>
```

Because `item` is an object.

---

Explanation about the results in the console, in your scenario:

Always: `{{item.name}}` It will print the value, this is why you see in the console:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="myFunc('Apple')" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Apple
</li>
```

Because you have in your page:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="myFunc('{{ item.name }}')">{{item.name}}
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` is actually an angular directive not an expression, you need to give brackets when you are passing value to the expression but you do not need to use brackets when you pass values to directive.